# How do i scroll backwards in the emacs help menu

Tags: linux, emacs

Today i tried emacs for the first time, and i found that C-h C-h opens up the help menu. The menu says press SPACE or DEL to scroll the menu. If i press SPACE, it scrolls me forward which is great, but SPACE doesnt go backwards, so i think i must press DEL to go backwards. But when i press DEL (on my laptop the key says 'Delete'), it just exits out of the menu and wherever the pointer was, it automatically inserts the text '[3~' . I know this is probably is something simple, but i dont get what is happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that by <kbd>Del</kbd>, they wanted me to use <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.